# Deleting diagonal elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given input

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Need output :

```
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

It is easy to use iteration or loop to do this, but there should be a neat way to do this without using loops. Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Approach #1**

One approach with `masking` -

```
A[~np.eye(A.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(A.shape[0],-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [395]: A
Out[395]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [396]: A[~np.eye(A.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(A.shape[0],-1)
Out[396]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

**Approach #2**

Using the regular pattern of non-diagonal elements that could be traced with broadcasted additions with range arrays -

```
m = A.shape[0]
idx = (np.arange(1,m+1) + (m+1)*np.arange(m-1)[:,None]).reshape(m,-1)
out = A.ravel()[idx]
```

**Approach #3** (Strides Strikes!)

Abusing the regular pattern of non-diagonal elements from previous approach, we can introduce [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) and some `slicing` help, like so -

```
m = A.shape[0]
strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
s0,s1 = A.strides
out = strided(A.ravel()[1:], shape=(m-1,m), strides=(s0+s1,s1)).reshape(m,-1)
```

---

**Runtime test**

Approaches as funcs :

```
def skip_diag_masking(A):
    return A[~np.eye(A.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(A.shape[0],-1)

def skip_diag_broadcasting(A):
    m = A.shape[0]
    idx = (np.arange(1,m+1) + (m+1)*np.arange(m-1)[:,None]).reshape(m,-1)
    return A.ravel()[idx]

def skip_diag_strided(A):
    m = A.shape[0]
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    s0,s1 = A.strides
    return strided(A.ravel()[1:], shape=(m-1,m), strides=(s0+s1,s1)).reshape(m,-1)
```

Timings -

```
In [528]: A = np.random.randint(11,99,(5000,5000))

In [529]: %timeit skip_diag_masking(A)
     ...: %timeit skip_diag_broadcasting(A)
     ...: %timeit skip_diag_strided(A)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 56.1 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 82.1 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 32.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hello @Divakar! Do you know how can I remove the diagonal from 4D matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Solution steps:

- Flatten your array
- Delete the location of the diagonal elements which is at the location `range(0, len(x_no_diag), len(x) + 1)`
- Reshape your array to (num_rows, num_columns - 1)

The function:

```
import numpy as np

def remove_diag(x):
    x_no_diag = np.ndarray.flatten(x)
    x_no_diag = np.delete(x_no_diag, range(0, len(x_no_diag), len(x) + 1), 0)
    x_no_diag = x_no_diag.reshape(len(x), len(x) - 1)
    return x_no_diag
```

Example:

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(5, size=(3,3))
array([[0, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 1],
       [2, 4, 0]])
>>> remove_diag(x)
array([[2, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [2, 4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to this party, but I have what I believe is a simper solution. So you want to remove the diagonal? Okay cool:

- replace it with NaN
- filter all but NaN (this converts to one dimensional as it can't assume the result will be square)
- reset the dimensionality

`

```
 arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).astype(np.float)
 np.fill_diagonal(arr, np.nan)
 arr[~np.isnan(arr)].reshape(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1] - 1)
```

Comment: You will have to convert the array to 'float' type (if it was not; int type array) to be able to fill it with NaN values. Otherwise, the following error occurs: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer. This approach is very slow as well compared to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63531391/11549398

Answer (score 2):

Just with numpy, assuming a square matrix:

`new_A = numpy.delete(A,range(0,A.shape[0]**2,(A.shape[0]+1))).reshape(A.shape[0],(A.shape[1]-1))`

Comment: If you're going to post an almost exact duplicate of an existing answer, please explain why yours is better.

Comment: the other one is wrong, in range(0,A.shape[0]**2,(A.shape[0]+1))  the +1 is missed.

Comment: You can mention other answer, where is the difference, or just simply post a comment telling that others miss something.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the cleanest way, based on [Divakar's first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46736275/1397061) but using `len(array)` instead of `array.shape[0]`, is:

```
array_without_diagonal = array[~np.eye(len(array), dtype=bool)].reshape(len(array), -1)
```

Comment: I like this one the most.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind creating a new array, then you can use list comprehension.

```
A = np.array([A[i][A[i] != A[i][i]] for i in range(len(A))])
```

Rerunning the same methods as @Divakar,

```
A = np.random.randint(11,99,(5000,5000))

skip_diag_masking
85.7 ms ± 1.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
skip_diag_broadcasting
163 ms ± 1.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
skip_diag_strided
52.5 ms ± 2.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
skip_diag_list_comp
101 ms ± 347 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I love all the answers here, but would like to add one in case your numpy object has more than 2-dimensions. In that case, you can use the following adjustment of Divakar's approach #1:

```
def remove_diag(A):
    removed = A[~np.eye(A.shape[0], dtype=bool)].reshape(A.shape[0], int(A.shape[0])-1, -1)
    return np.squeeze(removed)
```

Answer (score -1):

The other approach is to use numpy.delete(). assuming square matrix, you can use:

```
numpy.delete(A,range(0,A.shape[0]**2,A.shape[0])).reshape(A.shape[0],A.shape[1]-1)
```