# How to get a view on a cofactor of a 2D array column in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am using numpy.
I have defined a matrix Q as a 2D array. I want to get a view (i.e. I don't want to have a copy) of the i-th column without the i-th elements. For instance, the code in Matlab would be:

```
qi=Q(1:i-1 i+1:end, i)
```

What is the pythonic way to do it using slicing (I don't want to use np.delete)?

Thanks

Comment: I _suspect_ that it can't be done without fancy indexing, which will require a copy (happy to be proven wrong). In that case, could you settle with `0` values along the diagonal?

Comment: There's also [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46736275/4799172) if the point of avoiding the copy is not imperative (I'll have to test if any of those methods work in-place)

Comment: I think my answer reproduces what you want to achieve

Comment: @purpletentacle `Q` and `q` have different `id()` values and `print(np.may_share_memory(q, Q))` is `False`

Comment: But I might have read too much into the question. You only want a single row at a time rather than removing all values in one go?

Comment: I want a single row at a time, as a view, i.e. not a copy, if it is possible. I think that the solution of @purpletentacle makes a copy of the column.

Comment: I never understand why people downvotes valid questions :(

Comment: I don't think there is a way. Why does it have to be a view?

Comment: "i-th column without the i-th elements" do you want the entire cofactor of the matrix, (which is itself a matrix), or just the column?

Comment: just the column

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
`def partialMatrix(arr, row, col):
row -= 1
col -= 1
adjointArr = np.zeros((arr.shape[0]-1, arr.shape[1]-1))
r, c = 0, 0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i != row:
        for j in range(len(arr)):
            if j != col:
                adjointArr[r][c] = arr[i][j]
                c += 1
        r += 1
        c = 0   
return adjointArr`

`def cofactor(partial, row, col):
return (-1) ** (row + col) * np.linalg.det(partial)`
```

Comment: Hi, I am afraid that this solution makes a copy of the matrix. Besides, all those loops are probably not very efficient.