# List from Column elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a column 'List' for column 'Numbers' such that it gives a list leaving the element of the corresponding row in pandas.

```
Table:

| Numbers  | List           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | [2,3,4,1]      |
| 2        | [3,4,1,1]      |
| 3        | [4,1,1,2]      |
| 4        | [1,1,2,3]      |
| 1        | [1,2,3,4]      |
```

Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: Hey, please also share script with output so community can see what you tried and where you failed :).

Comment: You could try `df['List'] = [[n_ for n_ in df['Numbers'] if n_!=n] for n in df['Numbers']]`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.  I have changed the data a bit. Your solution is giving the right results when data is [1,2,3,4] but when it is [1,2,3,4,1] then it is failing. I have updated the table in question please have a look and help in getting the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For general solution working with duplicated values first repeat values by [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and then remove values of diagonal for delete value of row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':[1,2,3,4,1]})

A = np.tile(df['Numbers'], len(df)).reshape(-1, len(df))

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/46736275/2901002
df['new'] = A[~np.eye(A.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(A.shape[0],-1).tolist()
print (df)
0        1  [2, 3, 4, 1]
1        2  [1, 3, 4, 1]
2        3  [1, 2, 4, 1]
3        4  [1, 2, 3, 1]
4        1  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @AbhinavKhandelwal - For me working solution correct, added new data

Comment: yes, your solution is working fine in this case. Thanks for the help buddy!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':range(1, 5)})
df['list'] = df['numbers'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in df['numbers'] if i != x])
df
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.  I have changed the data a bit. Your solution is giving the right results when data is [1,2,3,4] but when it is [1,2,3,4,1] then it is failing. I have updated the table in question please have a look and help in getting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':[1,2,3,4,5]})

df['List'] = df['Numbers'].apply(
    # for every cell with element x in Numbers return Numbers without the element 
    lambda x: [y for y in df['Numbers'] if not y==x])
```

which results in:

```
df
   Numbers          List
0        1  [2, 3, 4, 5]
1        2  [1, 3, 4, 5]
2        3  [1, 2, 4, 5]
3        4  [1, 2, 3, 5]
4        5  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.  I have changed the data a bit. Your solution is giving the right results when data is [1,2,3,4] but when it is [1,2,3,4,1] then it is failing. I have updated the table in question please have a look and help in getting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Abhinar Khandelwal. If the task is to get any other number besides the current row value, than my answer can be fixed to the following:

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
numbers = rng.integers(5, size=7)

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':numbers})

df['list'] = df.reset_index()['index'].apply(lambda x: df[df.index != x].numbers.values)

df
```

But this way is much faster https://stackoverflow.com/a/73275614/18965699 :)